# Why Google is indexing Thumbnails and not Large images?

Tags: seo, google, html, search-engine-indexing

I have a page full of thumbnails, when clicked it opens the Full size image in new tab.

The problem is that Google is indexing the Thumbnail photos only, and leaves the Large images that it links to.

I need the **alt** attribute text of the Thumbnail to lead to the Original image when searched in Google Images.

My code is below:

```
<div class="thumb">
  <a href="images/wallpaper.jpg">
    <img src="images/wallpaper-small.jpg" target="_blank" alt="wallpaper-description">
  </a>
</div>
```

And this is an illustration of how my page works:
[image]

What I am doing wrong? what can be done to index Large images and leave Thumbnails?

Comment: Also, check through [Google's Image publishing guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016)

Comment: You can prevent Google from indexing the thumbnails using robots.txt or X-ROBOTS header

Comment: @DocRoot Thanks, I have read that article several times before.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes I did that on another page as a test, lets see how it goes.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that Google only sees one ALT tag therefore the other image is without description and will not rank in image search results.

*If using a lightbox then preferably you should code or use one that supports [HTML5 data-](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)* e.g:*

```
<div class="thumb">
    <img src="example.jpg" data-src="example-thumbnail.jpg" alt="example">
</div>
```

*If you are using only CSS and HTML then you **COULD** use one of 3 methods that I can think of:*

---

Method 1: Scrap the thumbnails and resize the larger image down to thumb size:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="example.jpg" alt="example">
</div>

/* CSS */
.thumbnail img {
    max-width: 200px;
}
.thumbnail img:hover {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

You could even spice this up by using a **[Pure CSS lightbox](https://codepen.io/gschier/pen/HCoqh)**

---

Method 2: Link to a valid page rather than a image:

```
<!-- Embedded Small -->
<a href="/path/to/example.html" title="View Image Full Size">
    <img src="example.jpg" alt="thumbnail of example">
</a>
```

---

Method 3: Show and Hide:

```
<!-- Both Images -->
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="example.jpg" alt="example">
    <img src="example-thumbnail.jpg" alt="example thumbnail">
</div>

/* CSS */
.thumbnail img:first-child {
    max-width: 200px;
}
.thumbnail img:last-child {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.thumbnail:hover img:first-child {
    display: none;
}
.thumbnail:hover img:last-child {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I am not using any Lightbox. its plain CSS/HTML as in the code and photo I have provided.

Comment: Okay, but the issue is the same. No ALT. Google can't index or rank images without a description, it does not use `<a title="">` or the filename.

Comment: Updated the answer but you simply can't do what you want Google to do without doing something similar, how ever much you dislike it, all major search engines work in this way.

Comment: Method 1 wont be ideal as the page contains hundreds of images, scaling down would slow down the page. Method 2 is not practical, as I would have to create thousands of pages. For Method 3 I have to take a look at that and see how it functions.

Comment: Method 1, 2 and 3 are slower. method 3 is slower than method 1 since it downloads both thumbnail and larger image since browsers download elements that are hidden.

Comment: In that case it wont be possible, we are talking 20MB per page download.

Comment: "Method 2 is not practical, as I would have to create thousands of pages." - assuming you have access to some kind of server-side scripting language then it's really just one additional page, with maybe some URL-rewriting to make the URL look "pretty". How are you writing the `alt` text on the thumbnail? How are you generating the thumbnail HTML?

Comment: @DocRoot Not using any server-side language, its hand coded with HTML/CSS only, I do write everything manually.

Comment: @DocRoot did you read the question? he/she is not using an ALT... that is the issue.

Comment: @MEGA I very much doubt Google will index 20mb images even if you add an alt description. Google's image bot actually download images and scans them before indexing furthermore, if a page does not load within 2-3 seconds that's considered both bad for UX and SEO, since Google rewards and punishes slow slights, and this includes all resources and all content. You should fix this with a 'DOWNLOAD' button using MIME tricks and then use  big thumbnails and index those instead. I recommend 5-10 at 1080p using jpeg 5-7 along with lossless compression page should be  around 1-2mb per a page then.

Comment: Also.... Browsers are notoriously bad for loading large images... 20mb compressed is hundreds of megabytes decompressed in a browser, particularly bad for laptop or mobile users, with that said it seems that your not willing to accept this :)

Comment: @SimonHayter Eh? Yes, I read (and understood) the question. And I agree with (and upvoted) your answer. And my comment says nothing to the contrary, so why question it? I am simply commenting on an earlier comment by the OP where they say they couldn't implement Method#2 (as suggested in your answer) because they have too many images.

Comment: @SimonHayter "I very much doubt Google will index 20mb images" - The "20MB" the OP refers to is for an entire page of 100's of full-size images (Methods#1 and #3 from your answer). So, that would be approx 200KB for the "fullsize" image given there are just 100 images per page. If only the thumbnail is used then the page itself will be only 100-200KB. From the comments, it seems the OP is very "willing to accept this" and is already very aware of this. (?)

Comment: Simon, @DocRoot to clear the confusion, the page itself with all thumbnails is around 500KB and loads pretty fast. 20MB is the size of original images withing "images" folder.

Comment: I have heard a lot of opinions regarding my issue, at the moment I am experimenting different methods which none require huge modification to the base code. like image Sitemaps.

Comment: Yes image sitemaps should work.

Answer (score 2):

For your images, you can apply the structured data as a property **[ImageObject](http://schema.org/ImageObject)**. Something like this: 
to **rdfa**

```
<div class="thumb" vocab=http://schema.org/ typeof=ImageObject>
<a href="images/wallpaper.jpg" title="wallpaper-description" property=contentUrl><img src='images/wallpaper-small.jpg' alt="wallpaper-description" property=thumbnailUrl></a></div>
```

to **microdata**

```
<div class="thumb" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
<a href="images/wallpaper.jpg" title="wallpaper-description" itemprop="contentUrl"><img src='images/wallpaper-small.jpg' alt="wallpaper-description" itemprop='thumbnailUrl'></a>
```

Check this on **[Google tester for structured data](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)**.

Comment: Another person have suggested Structured Data too, I am still confused on this structured data scene. Let me do some research of what it is exactly. Thanks.

Comment: To compress your images/thumbnail, you can use this tool https://imageoptim.com/online

Comment: ALT is not valid code within a HREF and will be ignored by Google and may cause problems with impaired users. Title tag is for HREF but is not factored in when indexing content.

Comment: @Simon Hayter I agree. So I changed my answer.

Comment: @nikant25 `src` within `<a>` is also not valid code.

Comment: @nikant25 using imageObject and structured data have worked. Would you please modify your answer so I can mark it. instead of "thumbnailUrl" to "thumbnail"

Answer (score 1):

The *target* attribute should be on the link and not the image. That is not your issue anyway. The real issue is that google has no idea what is in your images.

The real way to fix this is to create an image sitemap. The [Google documentation is here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636). Basically it lets you tell Google what is in the image, the caption, and give it a title. This not only allows Google to index it better, it allows then to provide better relevance to searches.

Comment: Do you mean I should include large image link and leave out the thumbnail? like this:
<image:loc>/images/large-image.jpg</image:loc>
<image:caption>Caption here</image:caption>
<image:title>Title here</image:caption>

Comment: No. Thumbnails are important but put the large images in the image sitemap and do not list the thumbnails there.

Comment: @Itai Google does not factor in title when ranking.

Comment: No but it does affect relevance and what is shown in results, even if it does not give rank.